# Why must I cast this generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a node that is Comparable, and only holds objects that are Comparable.

From what I understand of Java, the member variable `value` should be of type `E`, so later when I access it in `compareTo()`, it should still be of type `E`, and shouldn't need casting, but the compiler informs me this is not the case with:

`incompatible types: java.lang.Comparable cannot be converted to E`.

I think it should already be type `E`. Why must I cast `o.value` to type `E` in the first usage, but not in the second? What am I missing?

The code is below.

```
public class fakenode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<fakenode> {
 public E value;

 fakenode (E value)
 {
    this.value = value;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(fakenode o) {
    value.compareTo((E)o.value); // Why must I cast o to type E here?
    o.value.compareTo(value);    // This one works just fine

    return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left out the generic type parameter `E` from two of the places where you use the type `fakenode`.

It should be:

```
class fakenode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<fakenode<E>> { // first change
    public E value;

    fakenode (E value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(fakenode<E> o) { // second change
        value.compareTo(o.value);
        o.value.compareTo(value);

        return -1;
    }
}
```

I suppose this is not the actual logic of your `compareTo` method, though, since it always returns `-1`.

Comment: Ah. So I was actually making it lose it's type. That makes sense. And no, of course, this isn't the real logic. :-)

Comment: @kmort The Java compiler emits “raw type” warnings to let you know about mistakes like this.  It’s a good idea to enable all compiler warnings, since they usually indicate things like logical oversights or errors that are syntactically permitted but questionable.